# Uncertainity of measurement in both function and variable

Tags: experimental-physics, statistics

I have done a measurement of two physical quantities (let's call them x and z) at the same time and I have repeated the measurement five times. I have calculated the standard deviation and the uncertainity on the 95% confidence intervall of both x and z from the measurement results. Now I want to display z as function of x graphicaly. I am interested in the standard deviation and uncertainity of z as function of x. Should I somehow calculate them from both x and z measurement results or is the uncertainity of z(x) the same as of z and there is no influence on z by the quantity x?
I am sorry if this is a silly question but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.
Thank You very much!

Comment: Are you aware of the general formula for propagation of error?

Comment: Thank You, yes but I thought that this formula is only appliable for multiple variables of one function, as for example in y=f(x,z). But I don't know any formula that combines the errors of both function and variable (as in z(x)).

Comment: What is your mathematical relationship between z and x?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean. Please be much more specific. What have you measured exactly -- e.g. $x=temperature$ and $z=pressure$. What is the statistic you are interested in? The average value, the median etc? Please show us your plot $z$ vs. $x$. If you are interested in a linear relationship, please check how to perform a *linear regression*.